# Calendar JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have one index.html page and on this page I have three controls;

- one is for
  source
- second for destination
- third is for date/time.

Now I have source-destination like A-B then in calender control there is only certain day of certain month is only available .

For example if London-France is only available on only Monday from April to December means in calender only Monday is enable and all other date are disable.

I have lots of this types of source and destination and for all those source and destination this date and day is different ..

How can I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: hello.... Why negative marking..........??? i want some guideline not need code part...........

Comment: because no one can understand what you're trying to do. what have you tried? show us some source code and where specifically you're having problems. also, it's javascript, with a t.

Comment: @mark keep in mind that there are users from around the globe who frequent SO, English isn't everyones first language :)

Comment: @mark: i know, i wasn't trying to berate him for a misspelling... but it's generally easier to find information on a topic when you can spell it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general process would be to create an function to update the calendar picker you use. The function would check the current value of the source and destination and lookup the available dates. You can create an array of objects each object having a source, destination, valid and daterange variables. Create one object for each possible combinations. Loop through the object and update the calendar picker based on the valid dateranges.

Once the function is done hook it up to the `change` event for both the source and destination picker (I assume a `select` control, but if not, hook it into whatever control you use).